# How can I use :perldo in vim on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, perl, git-bash, msys

I installed Git Bash and vim was pre-installed. I personally would rather use PCREs instead of vim's regular expressions, so I tried doing `:perldo /s/foo/bar`. The error was that it could not find `msys-perl5_24.dll`. I looked in `/usr/bin` and it seemed that `msys-perl5_26.dll` was there instead.

I found [this repository](http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/) of msys packages and installed `perl-5.24.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`. I extracted it and replaced the files in `/usr/bin` with the ones I just extracted. Now, I get the error `ListUtil.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0x60029da70, needed 0x0)`. I'm assuming that the headers need to be updated in `/usr/lib/perl5` but I'm not sure where to find the headers. Is there an easier way to make `:perldo` work in vim? Or does it have to do with however they compile Git Bash?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the [`'perldll'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27perldll%27) Vim setting to point to the library that is present in your system.

Perhaps something like:

```
:set perldll=msys-perl5_26.dll
```

Or perhaps use a full path to it.

If the symbols for Perl 5.24 and 5.26 are similar enough (or, at least, 5.26 has all the symbols in 5.24, which is a good bet), it might work.

> Or does it have to do with however they compile Git Bash?

Yes, it probably does, it's probably the version of Perl they had installed on their build system, so that name got hardcoded as the library to look for.

> Is there an easier way to make `:perldo` work in vim?

You can use the [`:{range}!`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Arange%21) command to filter a range through an external command, in which case you can simply call an external Perl binary directly.

For example:

```
:%!perl -lpe 's/foo/bar/'
```

Or you could just use [Vim regular expressions](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html), they can be as powerful as PCREs in many cases. You might be interested in [the `\v` modifier](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cv), which makes Vim regexps "very magic", in which case you don't need to use backslash to access most meta-characters, making them somewhat more PCRE-like.